# How to make objects aligned according to a path or bitmap?

Tags: objects, particles

I have some objects **- balls -**, I need to make them organized according to a path or a bitmap.Is this possible without using manual object moves?

**EDIT:**

An example:

I'd like to organize/align my objects (balls) so that they occupy all dark pixels of this bitmap

[image]

Comment: do you want to influence the emission density using a texture ? if not please add more explanation to your post

Comment: No, I just need to make them statically aligned to a path or a bitmap. An example of what I need is to use a path, may be a text path, to align my objects to make them appear like text

Comment: Can you show an example of the effect from somewhere else?

Comment: I added an example of what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with a particle system where density is influenced by the image as a texture :

- create a plane and UV-unwrap it.
- add a particle system to this plane :

[image]

- in the texture tab change the influence from time to Density :

[image]

- the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- you need to create a path in blender, or just import it from other software
- the path should be converted into a mesh object
- now add a particle system to this path
- choose (Verts) under (emit from)
- select the other object that you want it to be duplicated on the path (under render select object and then choose the object name in the Dupli object field)
- put a check box on (Rotation) and choose (object Z) under initial orientation
- play with other options like the size, number, life time, until you get the object repeated on all the vertex that is on the path, and with the right size

done