# How do I make various objects point at/follow a path?

Tags: modifiers, objects, path

I'm trying to create a city street on a slope. I haven't found any methods that allow for several different objects to follow the same path, so maybe a path isn't the right method (still quite new to blender).

Essentially, I just want to be able to control the height and z-rotation of several objects at once. Here's a manually-arranged example:
[image]

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think this question have an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34483/how-to-make-objects-aligned-according-to-a-path-or-bitmap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely use a path.

1. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the first *house* and add two constraints.

   - A [Follow Path constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html#follow-path-constraint). Choose the Curve object as the *target*. Then check **Follow Curve** and **Fixed Position**. The offset has to vary for each object, for the first object we will leave it at `0.0`.
   - A [Limit Rotation constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/transform/limit_rotation.html#limit-rotation-constraint). Check **Limit X** and **Limit Y**. This prevents objects from tilting sideways. We only need the Z rotation.
     [image: constraint setup]
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>Select all other houses, lastly add the constrained object to the selection. Copy the constraints to all houses by going to *Objects > Constraints > Copy Constraints to Selected Objects*.
3. Adjust the **Offset** value for each house. E.g. [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]

[image]